# select data and sum of a column for a distinct column in data

Tags: sql

i have a table like this, (there is sum customers that each one has some payments):

```
customerID      Payments   InvoicCode
1                 1000         112
1                 250          456
2                 100          342
1                 20           232
2                 500          654
3                 300          230
```

what i want is like below (sum of a customer payments in each row):

```
customerID      Payments   InvoicCode   SumPayment
1                 1000         112        1270
1                 250          456        1270
2                 100          342        600
1                 20           232        1270
2                 500          654        600
3                 300          230        300
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not proper normal form to have wider-scoped data duplicated in multiple rows.  Think about the impact of updating a payment or adding a new customer payment will have - you will have to update all the relevant totals for that customer.

It would be simpler to create a view/stored procedure that gives you the totals at runtime which you can call whenever you need them:

```
create view CustomerTotals as

  select customerID
        ,sum(Payments) as SumPayment
    from mytable
group by customerID
```

Then you would reference this with `select * from CustomerTotals` with output like:

```
customerID      SumPayment
1               1270
2               600
3               300
```

Comment: Maybe so, but technically this doesn't answer the question. Also, don't presume too much - he may want that column to determine the percentage each row comprises.

Comment: Why not the simple select that the OP asked for?

Comment: @Bohemian,aF.: You are right, I will wait for response from OP and remove my answer if it is irrelevant.  I read the question as updating the totals into the original table as another column, which I re-read is not necessarily the intent. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 5):

Here it is:

```
SELECT t.customerID,
       t.Payments,
       t.InvoicCode,
       aux.SumPayment
FROM tablename t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT customerID,
        SUM(Payments) as SumPayment
 FROM tablename
 GROUP BY customerID) aux ON t.customerID = aux.customerID
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this, (*will mostly work on any rdbms*)

```
SELECT  a.*, b. totalPayment
FROM    paymentsTable a
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT customerID, SUM(Payments) totalPayment
                FROM paymentsTable
                GROUP BY customerID
            ) b ON a.customerID = b.customerID
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fcae/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
select t1.*,sumPay
from table t1,
(select customerID,sum(Payments) as sumPay
 from table
 group by customerID) t2
where t1.cutomerID=t2.customerID
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a view or try a select like this:

```
SELECT customerID, 
Payments, 
InvoicCode, 
(SELECT SUM(Payments) 
    FROM Customer IC 
    WHERE IC.customerID = OC.customerID )
FROM Customer  OC
```

Answer (score 3):

Join the table to a summed version of itself:

```
select mytable.customerID, Payments, InvoicCode, SumPayment
from mytable
join (select customerID, sum(Payments) as SumPayment from mytable group by 1) x
  on x.customerID = mytable.customerID
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a sub-query to get the total sum and then join that to your table to add the other columns.

```
SELECT x2.customerID
  , x2.payments
  , x2.invoice
  , x1.sumpayment
FROM
(
  select customerID
   ,sum(Payments) as SumPayment
  from yourtable
  group by customerID
) x1
inner join yourtable x2
  ON x1.customerID = x2.customerid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bdc1/3)

Answer (score 2):

For MSSQL

```
SELECT Т1.*, Т2.SumPayment
FROM TableName T1 INNER JOIN 
 ( SELECT customerId, SUM(Payments) SumPayment 
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY customerID  
) T2 ON T1.customerID = T2.customerId
```

Comment: this will work if the OP is using MySQL, but if MSSQL then it won't.

Comment: -1 No, it **won't work** for mysql! With mysql you'll only get the first row for each customerID, but he wants multiple rows for each customerID - read it again

Comment: In that case, I'll just leave MSSQL version. Anyway we have a huge number of right answers.

Comment: except yours... even with your deletion, your answer still doesn't work, although you're getting closer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your dbms is MS Sql-Server, you can use a `SUM(Payments)`with [`OVER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause :

```
SELECT customerID, Payments,InvoicCode
   ,SumPayment=SUM(Payments)OVER(PARTITION BY customerID)
FROM t
```

SQL-Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ac38/2/0

Answer (score 2):

## **[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf09e/1/0)**:

```
SELECT
       t.customerID     as customerID,
       t.Payments       as Payments,
       t.InvoicCode     as InvoicCode,
       total            as SumPayment
FROM
       theTable t, 
       (
          SELECT   customerId,
                   sum(Payments) as total
          FROM     theTable
          GROUP BY customerId
       ) tmp
WHERE  
       tmp.customerId = t.customerId
```